# Como cambio color de fondo de TabLayout Android Studio JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

no se porque aunque haga estos cambios sigue siendo de color blanco el fondo de mi tabLayout y el que quiero poner es un gris mas en concreto el `3D3D3D`. Es solo el indicador del tab ya que el fondo del fragmento si se pone gris

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    tabmode="fixed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    app:tabBackground="@color/grey"
    app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
    app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"

    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" />

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/view_pager2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
    android:background="@color/@color/grey" />
```

Asi me aparece en el la app

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: probaste comentando esta linea?     app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator" .. o puedes agregar el codigo? gracias!

Comment: Si, era justo eso vaya cosita mas tonta, muchas gracias^^ Ponmelo como respuesta y asi te doy el tick verde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el atributo `tabIndicator` se utiliza para darle la forma (bordes redondeados, etc) y algún gradiente si es deseado al tabIndicator. Depende cómo lo hayas armado al drawable, te puede sobrescribir el color que indiques en el atributo `tabIndicatorColor`. Una solución es eliminar la línea:

> app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"

Otra opción es darle el color dentro del drawable y setear el atributo de la siguiente manera:

> app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Se supone que al seleccionar el selector puedes pintarlo de un color y cuando se deseleccione el elemento lo pintas de otro color, para realizar esto debes usar un selector, crea uno en un archivo `tab_selector.xml` y guardalo en el directorio `/drawable` de tu proyecto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

ahora este `selector` usalo en tu `TabLayout`

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    ...
    ...    
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector.xml"
```